# redis session block in express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, redis

My system is using node.js(express) + redis + mysql + passport.js.

My goal:

- one user - one session only
- block other login access if a user login already

is there a sample code for this case ?

---

Last time, I developed as updating new session and removing old session.
But this case, the difficult points are

- if user does not logout properly? (close tab or browser)
- it keeps updating session in redis now.

Comment: When a user logs in, store that fact in redis, and presumably when they log out or the session expires, update redis.  I don't know if you will find something canned, but you could search for something that enforces concurrent number of users and then set that limit to 1.

Comment: Is there some data integrity issue why you are enforcing single access? Maybe with a higher understanding of the requirement an alternate solution could be provided.

Comment: @danblack it's a software requirement (higher level of cybercurity for customer's field I think) and it shouldn't be alternate. Competitive companies did it sadly.